# How to fix ViewState serialization error with my custom control?

Tags: asp.net, linq, serialization, viewstate

I'm writing my first asp.net user control.

It displays a list of locations that the user can select from.  I can load a list of locations into the control, and I can see what location the user selected when the page posts back, but the list itself is lost when the page posts back.

I populate the list with an object of type `IEnumerable<DetailedLocation>` where `DetailedLocation` is a class with several `string` fields.  When I try to put the list into ViewState, I get the following error:

```
Type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2  
[[DetailedLocation, AT.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0,  
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' in Assembly 'System.Core,  
Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not 
marked as serializable.
```

Certainly, my type can be marked serializable, but this error message persists.  I know that it must be possible to make this work somehow.  After all, I can pass an object of this type to a `GridView` and the data will persist thru postback.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've already marked your type as serializable, try saving the collection as List instead of IEnumerable.  I'm guessing under the IEnumerable interface is some sort of LINQ concrete collection type that's not serializable.